# How do I remove myself from somebody's Yahoo friends list?

Tags: yahoo, chat

In Yahoo, all the people who added me as a friend at some point of time (which may be back in 1999) can see me whenever I am online. Due to this issue I am always forced to go invisible in Yahoo, if I ever use it at all.

Is there a way I can remove myself from the friends list of unwanted people and thus stay truly incognito? After getting into bad terms with some chat friends, this had really become desirable.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about Yahoo Messenger?

Comment: Yes, messenger, of course. But now with the new interface chat is also there in the mail window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a contact on your Ignore List first, otherwise they can still see you when you are online and send you a message, because your ID is still on their Messenger list. Here's what to do:

1. Right click on their icon
2. Scroll down to stealth settings
3. Change them to appear permanently offline.
4. Then click on messenger (top left on the messenger window)
5. Click preferences
6. Scroll down to ignore list
7. Click and in the next window add them to your ignore list
8. Click OK
9. Then go back
10. Right click their icon and delete.

Note: there is a limit of 100 names that you can put on permanent ignore.

Also try:

- http://nobuddy.zak.2ya.com/
- http://www.vizgin.com/remover.php

which "claim" to remove you from their list.

All of this is untested by me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe with the latest version of Yahoo Messenger, you can set visible/invisible for specific friends (not the whole list) already

Answer (score 0):

If they're really unwanted, you can [add them to your ignore list.](http://help.yahoo.com/tutorials/ms8/mess/im_priv4.html)

> You can ignore a specific contact and stop all communication from the contact. You also appear offline to that contact’s Messenger List.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore list is limited and you need to maintain it.

If you deleted someone and you don't remember their ID, in order to ignore it, what do you do then?
You can always go in menu to **Messenger/Preferences** on Ignore list category. Select *Ignore anyone who is not in my Yahoo contacts*.

Future persons willing to contact you can always perform an *Add* request to you. If you accept them you will be able to chat.